# Is there any tool like snoop for windows phone app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I want to look at the Visual tree as like Snoop in WPF.. Is there any tool for Windows phone application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy) - [Silverlight Spy extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d50ee31-6426-4968-b00f-bd50ba54d74f).

Comment: But i need to get the licence for this...

Answer (score 3):

[XAML SPY](http://xamlspy.com/) is the updated Silverlight Spy.